# PacMan Grid 2D Array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, pacman

I'm supposed to make a simple type text PacMan game in Java and for the board I have to use a 2D array to make the grid. Here are the exact directions: At program startup, constructs and displays a 2-dimensional grid using standard array(s) (no collection classes allowed) with the size dynamically specified by the user (X and Y sizes can be different). Places the PacMan in the upper-left corner of the grid facing left All grid cells should have the empty cell character of ‘.’

This is my code so far, but I keep getting errors and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
public class myPacMan {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Choose an x value:");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Choose a y value:");
    int y = input.nextInt();
    int grid [][] = new int [x][y];
    int i, j = 0;
    for(i=0; i<x; i++);
    for(j=0; j<y; j++);
    System.out.print(grid[x][y] + ".");
}
```

}

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this is what comes up: objc[67753]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1035704c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x104df54e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Choose an x value:10
Choose a y value:10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at myPacMan.main(myPacMan.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.   First, remove the semicolons after your for loops.  Second, your print statement should use i and j, instead of x and y.  X and Y will always be one more than your array, so you'll get an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: thank you! I'm not getting errors anymore, but my grid is printing out as "0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yep.  You have several other problems, but at least this will get you started.  :D

Comment: LOL.  It's obviously homework, and you need to learn to do it yourself.  The one hint I will give you is try also using the println() method.